# Django-Tastypie significance?

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtREKCAWqBk&list=PLxxA5z-8B2xk4szCgFmgonNcCboyNneMD&index=17) tutorial link and was able to produce the same o/p as in this tutorial. Now, my question is apart from showing/representing database tables data in either xml/json format, what exactly is tasty pie used for?

Can I store the json format data in any variable?

Answer (score 0):

It's used to create [RESTful API's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

Tastypie's documentation outlines some common reasons why to use it:

- You need an API that is RESTful and uses HTTP well.
- You want to support deep relations.
- You DON'T want to have to write your own serializer to make the output right.
- You want an API framework that has little magic, very flexible and maps well to the problem domain.
- You want/need XML serialization that is treated equally to JSON (and YAML is there too).
- You want to support my perceived NIH syndrome, which is less about NIH and more about trying to help out friends/coworkers.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didnt get your 2nd(What do you mean by deep relations?),4th and 6th point. Plus Can I store the generated json format data in any variable?

Comment: store in a variable as if you want tastypie to generate a result and use that result in your view ? i think you can .. check this  http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-your-resource-in-regular-views

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by storing generated json in a variable. Deep relations are several models linked together. Magic and NIH are common programming terms. Google it and if you've got any more questions, create a new SO question.